# Django ModelForm CharField changed to ModelChoiceField results in not filled in values in edit mode

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model that has owner as CharField that should "house" the username  of the owner of the object. I am using a ModelForm to create the form to create the object and the same to edit it later on. Now I want this owner field to be a choice field with the usernames of the current users. This is easily done by adding owner = forms.ModelChoiceField.... to the ModelForm. This works for creating new objects.

Now  when editing (going to the /{object_id}/edit link using a GET request) the object I call the ModelForm with the object instance. All fields are then nicely filled in except for my owner field, that just shows the default '-----' and you have to reselect it again.

What I want is that that field is filled in with the value it currently is and I can then change it if I want based on the choices of current users.

Just to preempt this answer: I do not want to make owner a ForeignKey relationship with user.

My minified code:

```
Model:
class MyObjects(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True)

Form:
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = User.objects.all().only('username')
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__.......
        <bunch of code for self.fields error messages>

Edit view:
def edit_myobjects(request, object_id):
     i = get_object_from_id(object_id)
     if request.method == "POST":
          do the  updating
     else:
          form = MyModelForm(instance=i)
     return render(request, 'template.html', {'i': i, 'form': form, 'mode': 'edit'})
```

Tried the above and expected that the field for owner in the edit form was filled in based on the object received.
Also tried to put in initial in the creation of the form object in the view, but this didn't show any result either:

```
form = MyModelForm(initial={'owner': i.owner}, instance=i)
```

Tried to put the initial in the original creation of the owner parameter in the MyModelForm, but this showed the first choice of the list always as initial value instead of the '------' or the actual value that is expected.

Tried to put owner into a TypedChoiceField with type str, but that also just shows the first value in the list .

Small edit: When not specifying owner as a ChoiceField it works like you would expect but then the field is just an open text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After even more debugging and randomly trying I found a solution that works that combines some answers found on other posts. I can make the Widget for owner Select and give that choices in the class Meta part (tried it before in init but that didn't work, which makes sense from code flow I think).

Working code now (comments on bettering this are always appreciated!):

```
class Meta:
    owner_choices_base = User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True)
    owner_choices = [(c, c,) for c in owner_choices_base]
    owner_choices.insert(0, (None, None,))
    model = MyObjects
    widgets = {'owner': forms.Select(choices=owner_choices)}
```